# i am getting an error of undefined variable $nerd in my index.blade.php @foreach($nerds as $value) in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The reason I'm asking this is because I am creating a simple CRUD app. and I am getting an error of

> undefined variable $nerd

in my `index.blade.php`

I have used this variable in my controllers then called it in my view, but the error was generated

```
@foreach($nerds as $value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach you are putting

```
@foreach($nerds as $value)
```

When you want to access an individual nerd within the statement, you need to refer to it as `$value` not nerd. Or change your foreach to

```
@foreach($nerds as $nerd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the `$nerds` variable to the view you are rendering.

For example, in your controller:

```
view('yourview', ['nerds' => $nerds]);
```

Reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views

Answer (score 0):

In your **controller**

```
view('index', compact('nerds'));
```